# Spring Boot mongoTemplate not found

Tags: java, mongodb

I have Spring Boot app that creates a RESTful API. It wants to automatically connect to port 27017, I believe because it contains a transitive dependency to MongoDB.

But I don't want it to auto-connect to MongoDB because that server may not yet have started, thus throwing an error.

So I exclude the Mongo AutoConfiguration classes from the app like so:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

But then I get this error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.whatev.MyLogImpl required a bean named 'mongoTemplate' that could not be found.
```

Why does it need an mongoTemplate when I'm excluding Mongo AutoConfiguration?

But nonetheless, I then added a new @Configuration class containing MongoTemplate, but I get:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.whatevz.MongoFileService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate' that could not be found.
- Bean method 'gridFsTemplate' not loaded because auto-configuration 'MongoDataAutoConfiguration' was excluded
```

True, I excluded the MongoDataAutoConfiguration class. But I don't want to **also** exclude gridFsTemplate if that's gonna cause a problem. Sheesh.

All I want to do is **not** see an error when I start my app if MongoDB is not yet running.

Comment: Wju dont you comment your connection string in application.properties

Comment: I actually did that, but it still wants to connect to Mongo. Not totally sure why. I assume it's because my build.gradle has spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb as a dependency.